# Why doesn't this superclass run methods in a subclass during initialization?

Tags: python, oop

Why doesn't this code print `10`?

I was expecting the superclass to call the `__init_var` method in the subclass.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__init_var()

    def __init_var(self):
        self.var = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def __init_var(self):
        self.var = 10

print(B().var)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named your method `__init_var`with two initial underscores, making it a *class private method*. The name is mangled to make sure that subclasses don't clash with it. From the [*Reserved classes of identifiers* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes.

and in the [*Identifiers (Names)* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`.

So `A.__init_var` is renamed to `A._A__init_var`, and `A.__init__()` is altered to call `A._A__init_var()`. The renamed `B._B__init_var()` method is never called because it has a different name:

```
>>> dir(A)
['_A__init_var', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(A.__init__)  # disassemble the bytecode for A.__init__
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_A__init_var)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dir(B)
['_A__init_var', '_B__init_var', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
```

Remove one of those initial underscores, so name it `_init_var`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._init_var()

    def _init_var(self):
        self.var = 11

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def _init_var(self):
        self.var = 10
```